# Exchange fallover during power outage

Tags: exchange, outage

Ok, I have yet to find a definitive answer for this. I have an exchange server, and am trying to find a good fallover solution. If the power goes out what is the best way for me to hold my email until the server comes back onine?

Comment: This is not a forum - please don't edit your title with "SOLVED". Instead, please accept the answer below that was most helpful to you.

Answer (score 2):

If the power outage is short, you don't need to do anything. Other mail servers will simply retry again later. If you need to survive days-long outages, then you can use a third-party MX host to buffer your incoming email.

Answer (score 0):

Use a backup e-mail service.

Your MX records have a priority, if your primary MX server is unreachable, senders will try to deliver on the next one. Simply add a backup service with a low priority MX record, they will keep your e-mail for you till your own server is back online.

It's possible to do this with a second exchange server if you want to do everything yourself.

Google for "Backup e-mail service", you'll find lots of them.
One example is [Dyn e-mail backup](http://dyn.com/email/dyn-email-backup-mx/).

Wikipedia [has a lot of information on MX records and priority](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MX_record#The_backup_MX).